# PostgreSQL array и Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, mvc, postgresql

Существует ли возможность работать с полем таблицы, имеющим тип int[], используя Entity Framework?

Comment: да, если в класс контекста таблицы добавить такой аттрибут: `[Column("int_array", TypeName = "integer[]")`, где `int_array` - это ваше поле